# Adjust height dynamically when a FrameLayout is set as View.GONE

Tags: android, layout, height, space

I tried to use View.GONE in the Log-in row. When it's already gone, the Churvaness part will go down right above the global menus. The problem is that there will be a black space with the same height as the Log-in row right above the Churvaness. My scroll view will have a fix height.

How can I be able to dynamically change this height so that my list will fill the black space?

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Please include code when asking for help, it makes it hard for us to decipher what you're saying with only words.

From what I understand, the 'Churvaness' will drop down to the row where 'Login' sits. When that happens, there's an empty space above 'Churvaness'; therefore, you'd like to expand your 'Product/Price Cell Sheet' to fill that extra space.

**Solution:**

Use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on your 'Product/Price Cell Sheet'

**Note:** Update your question if you'd like a more accurate answer.